# Cannot assign value to LiveData variable while using launch() scope but can assign value to LiveData using runBlocking()

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `LiveData` variable that I want to assign a value to after receiving a response from a `HTTP request`. I assign this value inside the `launch {}` scope. However, when I test the code to see that the value has actually been assigned, the test fails stating that the value is `null`.

I have tried another option which is to use `runBlocking {}` scope instead of `launch {}` scope and my test case passes. The library used for networking is `Retrofit`

Below is the code that uses `launch()` and makes the test case **fail**.

```
private var _state = MutableLiveData<State>()
val state: LiveData<State>
  get() = _state 

private var job = Job()

private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)

init {
    executeRequest(....)
}

// Test cases fails with this function
private fun executeRequest(params) {
  uiScope.launch {
    val deferred = repository.getApi()
        .requestAsync(params)

    try {
        val response = deferred.await()

        _state.value = StateSuccess(response)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        _state.value = StateError("Failure: $e.message")
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the code that uses `runBlocking()` and makes the test case **pass**.

```
private var _state = MutableLiveData<State>()
val state: LiveData<State>
  get() = _state 

private var job = Job()

private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)

init {
    executeRequest(....)
}

// Test cases passes with this function
private fun executeRequest(params) {
  runBlocking {
    val deferred = repository.getApi()
        .requestAsync(params)

    try {
        val response = deferred.await()

        _state.value = StateSuccess(response)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        _state.value = StateError("Failure: $e.message")
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the test case

```
val viewModel = MyViewModel(fakeClientRepository)

val observer = Observer<State> {}

try {
    viewModel.state.observeForever(observer)

    assert(viewModel.state.value == StateSuccess("success"))
} finally {
    viewModel.state.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

Why is the `launch()` not assigning the value to the `LiveData` variable?

Comment: you have to check value in the `Observer`. in your test case `assert(viewModel.state.value == StateSuccess("success"))` is called immediately after `observeForever()` although your http request isn't done.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher, then assign value to the `LiveData`, using `postValue()` instead of `value` i.e.

```
private fun executeRequest(params) {
  uiScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO){
 val deferred = repository.getApi()
        .requestAsync(params)
    try {
        val response = deferred.await()
        _state.postValue(RESPONSE)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        _state.postValue(StateError("Failure: $e.message"))
    }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still having the same result, I also tried to make it a suspend function and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to become a suspend function. This is because you are calling going to be making a suspending operation within the function body, and in-order to do this the calling function must also be a suspending function. A suspending function is non-blocking and can be managed once triggered — such as being started, paused, resumed and cancelled.

```
   private suspend  fun executeRequest(params){
       job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
       val response = repository.getApi()
            .requestAsync(params).await()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          try {
             _state.value = StateSuccess(response)
          } catch (e: Exception) {
             _state.value = StateError("Failure: $e.message")
          }
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I tried this and the test case did not pass. I wrapped the above function is `launch` scope and that didn't work as well.

Comment: Ok instead of Dispatcher.Main use Dispatcher.IO and do a try.

Comment: I have updated my answer can you please try like this ?

Comment: The suspending operation is made inside `launch`, so no, the function itself doesn't need to be `suspend`.

Answer (score 0):

Your test case finishes before the request does and the value of `LiveData` changes. With `runBlocking`, `executeRequest` (and so your constructor) only returns when the block does; with `launch` it launches it in a separate `Job` and returns immediately.

If you really need to do it in the constructor, you could assign the `Job` to a field e.g.

```
private var _state = MutableLiveData<State>()
val state: LiveData<State>
  get() = _state 

private var job = Job()

private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)

internal val requestJob = executeRequest(....)

private fun executeRequest(params): Job = uiScope.launch {
    try {
        val deferred = repository.getApi()
            .requestAsync(params)

        val response = deferred.await()

        _state.value = StateSuccess(response)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        _state.value = StateError("Failure: $e.message")
    }
}
```

and then call `requestJob.await()` in your test case before checking the value, e.g.

```
val viewModel = MyViewModel(fakeClientRepository)

val observer = Observer<State> {}

runBlocking { 
    viewModel.requestJob.await()
}

try {
    viewModel.state.observeForever(observer)

    assert(viewModel.state.value == StateSuccess("success"))
} finally {
    viewModel.state.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

Comment: I have attached my test case.

Comment: Yes, this test case should give the result described. I added how you would modify it (but I don't see why you use `observer` at all).

Comment: I'm using the `observer` because I'd like to observe when that value changes in the UI.